# react app is not running, missing start script

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to run my application using npm start and this error occurs, I added to package.json in scripts "start": "node index.js" where index is the starting point of the application and still giving this error! any help??
`npm ERR! missing script: start`

Comment: try this  `npm cache clean --force` and    `npm i react-scripts`

Comment: If this above doesn't work, please post your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

One Simple hack you can do is, create a new app with CRA and then replace your existing code into that